# Export-AzureRmAutomationDscConfiguration Unable to deserialize the response

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, dsc

I'm making a call to download a DSC configuration file from an Azure automation account like this;

`Export-AzureRmAutomationDscConfiguration -ResourceGroupName "GROUP_NAME" -AutomationAccountName "ACCOUNT_NAME" -Name $CurrentName -Force -OutputFolder $OutputFolder -ErrorAction Stop`

However the call is failing with an error;

```
Export-AzureRmAutomationDscConfiguration : Unable to deserialize the response.
At line:27 char:9
+         Export-AzureRmAutomationDscConfiguration -Debug -ResourceGrou ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Export-AzureRmAutomationDscConfiguration], SerializationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Automation.Cmdlet.ExportAzureAutomationDscConfiguration
```

Running the command with the `-Debug` parameter shows the script being partly downloaded and then a message `DATA TRUNCATED DUE TO SIZE`. If I download the script manually it 99Kb.

This has only just started occuring, the file used to download quite happily. So why would this error now be happening?

Comment: No, I won't have the time to test that for couple of weeks, but thanks a lot for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old `AzureRm` module, try to [migrate it from AzureRM to Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-3.8.0), then use the new `Az` command [`Export-AzAutomationDscConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.automation/export-azautomationdscconfiguration?view=azps-3.8.0).

```
Export-AzAutomationDscConfiguration -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup01" -AutomationAccountName "AutomationAccount01" -Name "Configuration01" -Slot Published -OutputFolder "C:\Users\PattiFuller\Desktop"
```